# Weld container doesn't inject proper object, it returns NULL

Tags: java, cdi, inject, weld

I am playing around with Weld CDI configuration. I got stuck with NULL being returned. Theoritically my configuration should make proper object instance created but I can't find reason it doesn't...

I looked up for similar questions, but most issues were related to use of *new* keyword while instantating the object. The other advise is to use application server. I'm running wildfly, so it's not the case as well.

Log:

```
Feb 17, 2021 12:12:18 AM org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup <clinit>
INFO: WELD-000900: 4.0.0 (Final)
Feb 17, 2021 12:12:19 AM org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup startContainer
INFO: WELD-000101: Transactional services not available. Injection of @Inject UserTransaction not available. Transactional observers will be invoked synchronously.
Feb 17, 2021 12:12:19 AM org.jboss.weld.environment.se.WeldContainer fireContainerInitializedEvent
INFO: WELD-ENV-002003: Weld SE container 75c04868-bd06-4acb-874c-db603ada27b0 initialized
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at MessagePrinter.printMessage(MessagePrinter.java:9)
    at Main.main(Main.java:10)
Weld SE container 75c04868-bd06-4acb-874c-db603ada27b0 shut down by shutdown hook

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here's my setup:

**beans.xml** simple as can be

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<beans bean-discovery-mode="all" version="1.1"
       xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
  http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"/>
```

**Main class** - creating Weld container

```
import org.jboss.weld.environment.se.Weld;
import org.jboss.weld.environment.se.WeldContainer;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Weld weld = new Weld();
        WeldContainer container = weld.initialize();

        MessagePrinter printer = container.select(MessagePrinter.class).get();
        printer.printMessage();

        weld.shutdown();
    }
}
```

**MessagePrinter class**

```
import javax.inject.Inject;

public class MessagePrinter {

    @Inject
    private MessageProducer messageProducer;

    public void printMessage() {
        String message = messageProducer.getMessage();
        System.out.println(message);
    }
}
```

So above MessageProducer variable is always null although one only existing MessageProducer implementation (mark as @default) should be injected...

**MessageProducer interface**

```
public interface MessageProducer {

    public String getMessage();
}
```

**SimpleMessageProducer class (MessageProducer implementation)**

```
import javax.enterprise.inject.Any;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Default;

@Default
@Any
public class SimpleMessageProducer implements MessageProducer {

    @Override
    public String getMessage()  {
        return "Example message " + System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}
```

Project structure:

```
-src 
--java 
---FileMessage 
---FileMessageProducer 
---Main 
---MessagePrinter 
---MessageProducer 
---SimpleMessageProducer 
-resources 
--META-INF 
---beans.xml
```

Comment: It clearly looks like that Weld didn't identify your `beans.xml`. How is your project structure setup for this?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however I think the Weld sees the beans configuration. Whenever I remove it or move it I get exception _"WELD-ENV-000016: Missing beans.xml file in META-INF"_

Also, I added project structure to the origin post.

Comment: I'm not sure, but you may need an explicit no-args constructor in the `SimpleMessageProducer` implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using Weld 4.0.0.Final, you should use jakarta.inject namespace instead of javax.inject.

You probably are having issues due overlapping classpaths. Keep only the org.jboss.weld.se:weld-se-core:4.0.0.Final dependency and you will probably be fine.

Comment: Oh, good man. It was answer to all my problems. Changed "@Inject" and "@Default" to relate to jakarta and it works pefectly. Thank you! :)